# BlockUI for a certain <div> only

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to block a div (with id="blockme") in my page that contains a gridview while the gridview is loading. I found the code below at [Github](https://gist.github.com/whoshotjr/3010693) but this code blocks the whole page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Page = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        Page.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
        Page.add_endRequest(endRequest);

        function OnBeginRequest(sender, args) {
            $.blockUI();
        }
        function endRequest(sender, args) {
            $.unblockUI();
        }

 </script>
```

I looked into stackoverflow and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064079/how-to-display-a-loading-image-until-a-gridview-is-fully-loaded-without-ajax-too) answer which shows how to block a certain div on button click.

My problem is that I don't want to use the button click event but use page begin request and end request instead events to block my div.

I tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
    function OnBeginRequest(sender, args) {
        $('#blockme').blockUI();
    }
    function endRequest(sender, args) {
        $('#blockme').unblockUI();
    }
```

Comment: The link you provided has a solution to Trigger the event at Page Load. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: It adds a hidden button and uses a click event, I wanted to know if it's possible to use the page request and end request instead

Comment: @aRrOwDreWLs, thank you for your suggestion, actually I found a helpful question on SO mentioned in my answer, and it says that blockUI is only used to block the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two links helped me solve it [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304637/jquery-blockui-element-blocking)

Here's how it worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Page = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        Page.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
        Page.add_endRequest(endRequest);

        function OnBeginRequest(sender, args) {
            $('div#blockme').block({
                message: '' ,
                overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#fff'   }
             });
        }
        function endRequest(sender, args) {
            $('div#blockme').unblock();
        }

 </script>
```